# Unity predict endpoint from current velocity

Tags: unity-game-engine, velocity, gravity

My rocket's rigidbody velocity is Vector2(0,100) when I call a function. How can I calculate the world coordinate (enpoint) when the velocity reaches 0?

Gravity should be included in the formula.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the integral of the velocity function, which should provide the total distance respective to time.

Your velocity is going to be v = (100 - ('t'ime * 'g'ravity)). We can solve for time like t = (-v + 100)/g -> t = (0 + 100)/g = 100/g. So you should reach zero velocity at t = 100/g (assuming all the same units).

The integral of your velocity will give you distance traveled. An integral calculator is here: http://www.integral-calculator.com/

The integral function of your velocity is 100t - (g*t^2)/2

From zero to a particular time t, you can just plug and play. So for example, if for a particular gravity you reach zero velocity at t = 10 seconds, you will have traveled (100 * 10) - ((g * 10^2)/2) distance. (so for gravity 9, you would get 1000 - (9 * 100)/2 = 550 units

Edit: To be clear - first you want to calculate how long it takes to get to velocity zero at a particular starting velocity and gravity:

> t = vStart/g

Then plug that time value into the integral function above:

> distance = (vStart * t) - ((g * t^2)/2)

(or clearly you could turn it into one function by replacing t with vStart/g in the second function, but if I were coding I would definitely calculate them in two steps to provide a sanity check in case my units were wrong)